# Postgresql Docker container not receiving TCP requests in swarm mode

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-swarm, docker-network, esxi

I am not quite sure where my problem is, I can only describe some symtoms, so please be patient with error logs/configurations.

I want to install a HA postgresql database. The easiest ways to me seems to do it via preconfigured docker images.
I am using the [bitnami postgresql image](https://github.com/bitnami/containers/tree/main/bitnami/postgresql#using-the-command-line) for this with the following configuration in swarm mode on two separate nodes.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgresql-master:
    image: 'docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:15'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    networks:
      - postgres_network
    volumes:
      - '/localVol:/bitnami/postgresql'
    environment:
      - POSTGRESQL_REPLICATION_MODE=master
      - POSTGRESQL_REPLICATION_USER=repmgr_username
      - POSTGRESQL_REPLICATION_PASSWORD=repmgr_password
      - POSTGRESQL_USERNAME=username
      - POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=dbname
      - POSTGRESQL_SYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT_MODE=on
      - POSTGRESQL_NUM_SYNCHRONOUS_REPLICAS=1

    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.type == primary

  postgresql-slave:
    image: 'docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:15'
    ports:
      - '5432'
    networks:
      - postgres_network
    depends_on:
      - postgresql-master
    environment:
      - POSTGRESQL_USERNAME=username
      - POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRESQL_REPLICATION_MODE=slave
      - POSTGRESQL_REPLICATION_USER=repmgr_username
      - POSTGRESQL_REPLICATION_PASSWORD=repmgr_password
      - POSTGRESQL_MASTER_HOST=postgresql-master
      - POSTGRESQL_MASTER_PORT_NUMBER=5432
    volumes:
      - '/localVol:/bitnami/postgresql'
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.type != primary
networks:
  postgres_network:
    driver: overlay
    external: false
    internal: true
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.70.1.0/24
```

The swarm is created via a simple `init` command and the node is joined via the `join` command. No extra config.

When running this file with `docker compose up` (without the deploy constraints) on one host, the two containers are up and running, replicating the database and so on. Working as desired.

When running this file as is with `docker stack up`, the primary is running and stable, the secondary is not; see logs

**Primary**

```
postgresql 14:07:57.00 INFO  ==> ** Starting PostgreSQL setup **
postgresql 14:07:57.06 INFO  ==> Validating settings in POSTGRESQL_* env vars..
postgresql 14:07:57.07 INFO  ==> Loading custom pre-init scripts...
postgresql 14:07:57.09 INFO  ==> Initializing PostgreSQL database...
postgresql 14:07:57.10 INFO  ==> Custom configuration /opt/bitnami/postgresql/conf/pg_hba.conf detected
postgresql 14:07:57.17 INFO  ==> Deploying PostgreSQL with persisted data...
postgresql 14:07:57.21 INFO  ==> Configuring replication parameters
postgresql 14:07:57.28 INFO  ==> Configuring fsync
postgresql 14:07:57.31 INFO  ==> Loading custom scripts...
postgresql 14:07:57.31 INFO  ==> Enabling remote connections
postgresql 14:07:57.33 INFO  ==> ** PostgreSQL setup finished! **
postgresql 14:07:57.34 INFO  ==> ** Starting PostgreSQL **
2022-11-16 14:07:57.363 GMT [1] LOG:  pgaudit extension initialized
2022-11-16 14:07:57.374 GMT [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.0 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2022-11-16 14:07:57.377 GMT [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2022-11-16 14:07:57.378 GMT [1] LOG:  could not create IPv6 socket for address "::": Address family not supported by protocol
2022-11-16 14:07:57.380 GMT [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2022-11-16 14:07:57.384 GMT [83] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-11-16 14:07:36 GMT
2022-11-16 14:07:57.392 GMT [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

**secondary**

```
postgresql 14:40:51.58 INFO  ==> ** Starting PostgreSQL setup **
postgresql 14:40:51.64 INFO  ==> Validating settings in POSTGRESQL_* env vars..
postgresql 14:40:51.65 INFO  ==> Loading custom pre-init scripts...
postgresql 14:40:51.66 INFO  ==> Initializing PostgreSQL database...
postgresql 14:40:51.70 INFO  ==> pg_hba.conf file not detected. Generating it...
postgresql 14:40:51.70 INFO  ==> Generating local authentication configuration
postgresql 14:40:51.74 INFO  ==> Waiting for replication master to accept connections (60 timeout)...
postgresql-master:5432 - no response
```

The secondary restarts itself after a time of constantly logging *no response*.

I have tried pinging the containers which works. Also when exposing the port of the primary to the host, it is possible to access the database from the host BUT it is not possible to send any TCP traffic to both container as tried with netcat and tcpdump. Netcat is able to send packets, but tcpdump on the primary and secondary does not show requests.

Anybody got a tip for me?

Comment: does it work if you just declare the network without specifying any overrides?

Comment: Also, without failover, this cannot be characterised as HA.If you are planning on supporting failover, then host networking for the published port, or some kind of proxy to :5432 direct traffic to the primary node will be required, as well as monitoring to determine when to switch over.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not change anything.

Comment: Well, I just deployed your stack to my swarm and the master and replicas connected. If this is a new swarm, I'd posit that there is a firewall issue preventing overlay networks connecting properly. You've checked that the overlay networking ports are open between nodes?

Comment: Yes. The nodes are in the same network, so no firewall except iptables in between and these were opened according to https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/
There is only UDP and TCP traffic happening between nodes, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the error.

As someone states in his [blog](https://www.rendrag.net/2019/08/setting-up-docker-swarmin-vmware-nsx), a specific port (4789) is blocked when virtualising with an ESXi stack. This is the default port for overlay network traffic.

Simply changing that port when initialising a swarm solves the problem.

```
docker swarm init --data-path-port 4788
```